# Ceaser Cipher - incorrect for upper case letter

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

My attempt at using a Caeser Cipher is failing on capital letters has incorrect results.

> **input:** All-convoYs-9-be:Alert1.  **and rotation factor is** 200
>
> **Correct output:** Epp-gsrzsCw-3-fi:Epivx5.
>
> **My result:**
> _pp-gsrzs]w-3-fi:_pivx5.

```
String rotationalCipher(String input, int rotationFactor) {
       
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for(char c : chars){
         if(Character.isLetter(c)){
            int currentPos = c - 'a';
          int newPos = (currentPos + rotationFactor) % 26;
          char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newPos);
           sb.append(newCharacter);
         }else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
           String y = Character.toString(c);
           int x = Integer.parseInt(translateNumber(y,rotationFactor));
           sb.append(x);
         }else {
           sb.append(c);
         }
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
      }

String translateNumber(String oldNumber, int rotationFactor){
    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(oldNumber);
    int newNumber = n + rotationFactor;
    
    
    if(newNumber > 10){
      newNumber = newNumber % 10;
    }
    
    return String.valueOf(newNumber);
  }
  
  int verifyRotationFactor(int rotationFactor){
    int max = 26;
    int div = rotationFactor / max;
    if(div > 1){
      return div;
    }
    
    return rotationFactor;
  }
```

I'm very new to this, not sure what I need to fix.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Set a breakpoint and step step step.

Comment: You are doing a MOD 26 but you have both upper and lower case letters,  There are some characters between the upper and lowercase letters. You also have a ‘-’ sign and numbers that are below  the uppercase letters.  1) define what chars you will allow for input. 2) fine what the total distance is of the char set.  Get a printout or table of ASCII chars and see what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ASCII related problem to me. You should shift position of letter in an array that contains letters. In your way it shifts letters by ASCII order.
So

- It finds C and replace it with "]"
- It finds E and replace it with "_"
- If it would find B, the program will return "\" eventually.

> BECAUSE THERE IS NON-ALPHANUMERIC VALUES BETWEEN LETTERS IN ASCII
> TABLE.

more info: [https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.html](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm)

In order to make cipher work better, you need an array to loop inside.